# Flutter cloud message and notification

Tags: flutter, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build feature with cloud message and notification.First I try make FCM automatically displays notification and its work and receive message all times.but when click the notification it only pop to main route.I want a feature like I can pop to specific route or pop muitiple routes(like pop main route first and pop chatroom route at the top make user can press "back" button go back to main route).Then I trying to do with [Flutter Local Notifications Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications).But seems this library not show notification when app is terminated only shows when app is background or forground. Anyone have better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to configure the app to receive the click event (configure FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK) like described in https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#android-integration

Then you need to configure the app to receive the data from the notification:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'));
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('AlternativeRouteName');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('AlternativeRouteName');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'));
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('AlternativeRouteName');
      },
    );
```

(Read this section to learn more about which event is trigged in iOS and Android https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages )

Then you can trigger correct Route based on the data of the Message...

Comment: I don't know is this related to my question? This just a base of fcm setup If you using fcm you must knew it.the issue is fcm won't show when app is terminated.

Comment: It just happens when is a Data message only. If you send a Notification with data it works...

Comment: Yeah I knew. But problem is how to pop to specific route or pop multiple route when you click notification tab.not  just open app. This is what am I ask in this question.

Comment: I edited my answer.... You must start the messaging in you root Route. Them you can use a `pushNamed` or a `Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'));`and them a `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('AlternativeRouteName');`

Comment: I have big misunderstand of how those 3 callbacks work cause I read documents too quick.Sorry it's my bad.you are right.